# jQuery scoped settings for plugin based on Plugins/Authoring article

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, scope

I have a jQuery plugin which follows the Plugins/Authoring example from docs.jQuery.com and I am having trouble figuring out how to keep unique settings for each element the plugin is applied to. There are two elements on the page each having the plugin applied to them separately.

Here is my code so far:

```
(function( $ ) {

/* Default settings */
var defaults = {
    id: null,
    properties: null,
    container: '.comp-settings', /* override for .retail or .distressed */
    priceLabel: '.comp-section-header span',
    slide: slideCallback,
    minRange: 100000
};

/* Some public here: $.compSlider('method', options) */
var methods = {
    init: function( options ) {

        var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).slider( settings );
        });

    }
}

/* Some methods here */
function opt( name ) {
    return settings[ name ];
}

/* Plugin namespace */
$.fn.compSlider = function( method ) {
    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else if ( typeof method === 'string' ) {
        return this.slider( method, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );
    }
};

})( jQuery )
```

Issues:

1. The settings variable isn't accessible in the plugins functions
2. If I store the settings variable in $(this).data('settings') I still can't access $(this).data('settings') from the 'opt' function because "this" isn't the element (I believe it's the DOM window.)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the settings in the `compSlider` function because in your example they are defined in `init()`, making them local to that function.  If you moved the declaration up in scope:

```
$.fn.compSlider = function( method, options ) {
    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
};
```

Then you'd be able to access it there.  Or just defining it (`var settings;`) in compSlider and removing `var` in `init()` would be enough.

Update:

In repsonse to your comment, yes, sorry, forgot about the issue #2.  As it is, you will not be able to access the settings for each plugin object because you cannot "go down" in scope.  In other words, you cannot access a local variable of a function from outside of that function.  And that is what settings are, local to the `compSlider` function (if you use the structure I proposed), they are lower in scope as far as your `opt()` function is concerned.

You can, of course, always go up in scope.  To achieve this you could set up a variable in the plugin's global space that stores references to all objects created.

```
var compSliderObjects = [];

$.fn.compSlider = function( method, options ) {
    //store objects in compSliderObjects
};
```

However, this is just the an idea, and you still need to figure out how you want to access the compSliderObjects and pull the right settings.  Will each object have a unique id?  If so, an array of objects (`{id: 2, settings: data}`).  If not, you need to figure out how you want to uniquely identify them and pull them from the array.

Also, do you really need to access them globally?  It's less work and code to just call the object and get the settings (as shown in the fiddle).

Comment: 150lbs: I tested this and it didn't work. The problem still existed where the latest element to have the .compSlider() method applied to it would update all "settings" for every other element that had previously hd .compSlider() applied. You can see two different DOM objects here, both of which had different settings, however both of which are showing the same settings (settings.container which is a selector): http://cl.ly/0u0L1i433V3m1d2V0B1Z

Comment: Not exactly sure where you are going wrong then, but I put up a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/kFL5N/.  I'm not sure that's what you want to do, but it demonstrates seperate settings for each instantiation.

Comment: 150PoundsOfDonamite: See "issue #2" in the original post. I think I may just do the method you are suggesting, though.

Comment: 150PoundsOfDonamite: So I just used your suggestion, saved to $(this).data, and then the non-callback methods (no access to 'this') get settings passed in explicitly, thanks!

Comment: 150PoundsOfDonamite:

So it turns out that using .data() was a good move because it makes a copy of the 'settings' object and the settings are no longer overwritten by the next instantiation of a compSlider object.

I just didn't like having to call .data() everywhere in order to retrieve the 'settings' but it's OK and it's working well now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it, David, and you're welcome!  Mind hookin a guy up with some points, too (The check + up arrow)?